# c# 'sideloading' nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

I'd like to edit some packages and contribute to the github repositories. I am concerned with the workflow however.

I want to edit/debug packages I would like to edit (so include the source code in some way) is the best method of action here to just put the github repo in my own repository to create something?

Or do I have to build, publish to local NuGet repository, include in my own repository to check if it plays nice with my own project?

Comment: If you're contributing to a third part project, be less concerned that it plays nice with your project and more than your project plays nice with it. Having said that, there's nothing special about Nuget packages, they're just a handy way to distribute DLLs.

Comment: I just thought that sort of 'sideloading' creates an environment in which i can easily add stuff or at the very least scroll through the files a bit easier to put in break points to know how it works.

Comment: Just reference the projects in the same way you would any other project.

Comment: @DavidG blew my mind. Thanks! Didnt know about referencing another project..

Comment: I think the word "Nuget" just confuses people sometimes. Remember, it's just a zip file with some stuff in it. Try downloading the `.nupkg` directly from Nuget and rename it to `.zip`...

Comment: woah. Thanks! I checked out the github repository and added it to my project as a reference. This makes my life way easier! Blowing my mind every step of the way my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else looking for an answer: here it is, from @DavidG.

1. Check out the project in a folder you know
2. Open your solution.
3. click on  `File > Add > Existing Project...`
4. Reference your other project

and there you go. Its simple and I wish I had thought of it earlier.